# Inheritance helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have close to 25 deployments and services.  Each Helm template has the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aa1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aa1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: {{ .Values.env1 }}
          value: "yes"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: {{ .Values.v1 }}
          mountPath: {{ .Values.v1monthPath}}
          subPath: {{ .Values.v1subpath }}
```

Similarly I have same `env` and `volumeMount` defined for all 25 templates.

Is there any way I can use template inheritance in Helm?

Answer (score 3):

A single Helm `.tpl` file can contain multiple YAML documents, separated with the `---` start-of-document separator.  Also, you can use all of the standard Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) capabilities, including its looping constructs.

That means that you could write a template like this:

```
{{- $top := . -}}
{{- range .Values.names -}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ . }}
spec:
  ...
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: {{ $top.Values.env1 }}
          value: "yes"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ . }}
spec: { ... }
{{ end -}}
```

What this does is first to save away the current context; since `range` resets the current template default context `.` to the iterator value, we need to remember what its current value is.  We then iterate through every value in a list from the values file.  (The [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) [`list`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) function could create the list in the template.)  For each item, we create a Deployment and a Service, each starting with a `---` on its own line.  When we need the current name, it is `.`; when we need something from the Helm values, we need to explicitly look it up in `$top.Values`.

Another possible approach is to write separate templates for the deployment and service, and then have files invoke each of them.  Technically a template only takes one parameter, but you can use `list` and `index` to have that one parameter be a list.

```
{{/* _deployment.tpl */}}
{{- define "deployment" -}}
{{- $name := index 0 . -}}
{{- $top := index 1 . -}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
name: {{ $name }}
...
name: {{ $top.Values.env1 }}
...
{{ end -}}
```

```
{{/* aa1.yaml */}}
{{- template "deployment" (list "aa1" .) -}}
{{- template "service" (list "aa1" .) -}}
```

This can get almost arbitrarily complex (you can have conditionals based on the current object name; you can use the template `index` function to look up values in the values object; and so on).  `helm template` will do some validation and write the rendered template to stdout without invoking Kubernetes, which is helpful for eyeballing it and can be a basis for automated tests.

The text/template "inheritance" capabilities (using *e.g.* `block`) aren't a good match here.  The documentation for [`(*text/template.Template).Parse`](https://godoc.org/text/template#Template.Parse) notes that, if `Parse` is called multiple times, the last `define` found wins, which gives you a room to `Parse` a base template with a placeholder `block` and then `Parse` a refined template that redefines that.  Helm doesn't really use this functionality; while it loads all of the YAML and supporting template files into the same template instance, it renders all of the top-level files separately instead of rendering some root template that allows for overrides.